# How to read firebase configuration from an angular web application?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire

I have an Angular application where I use the `environment.ts` to store api keys and other configuration. I want to deploy this application to Firebase so I can move the config form environment files to the Firebase config so I set the variables as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)

Then when I run the command `firebase functions:config:get` I correctly get the configuration I expect. But now I don't know how to get this config in my Angular project. What I've done until now is create an app in the Firebase so I've the config in `environment.ts` like this:

```
    firebase: {
        apiKey: 'apiKey',
        // Other properties
    },
```

And in `app.module.ts`:

```
    imports: [
        // ...
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    ],
```

But from here I don't know how to get the config. I tried with the npm package `firebase-functions` and run `functions.config()` but I get a lot of error for libraries like `fs`, `zlib` etc. I guess is not meant for client side use.

How can I get the Firebase config from the Angular app?

Comment: Do you mean where do you find the Firebase configuration in your Firebase Angular Project? or show/display your Firebase Configuration in Angular App  using Angular codes?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have same question

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the functions config on the client-side, as the functions config is going to include administrative access to your project.

At the moment AngularFire doesn't support dynamic loading of the Firebase configuration, so you'll want to bake it into the your environment before you deploy.